# How to implement the 24 solar terms in Lisp with Emacs Calendar

Tags: emacs, calendar, lisp, elisp

I tried to learn the code in cal-china.el in Emacs source code and found the following code:

```
;;;###holiday-autoload
(defun holiday-chinese-winter-solstice ()
  "Date of Chinese winter solstice, if visible in calendar.
Returns (((MONTH DAY YEAR) TEXT)), where the date is Gregorian."
  (when (memq displayed-month '(11 12 1)) ; is December visible?
    (list (list (calendar-gregorian-from-absolute
             (calendar-chinese-zodiac-sign-on-or-after
              (calendar-absolute-from-gregorian
               (list 12 15 (if (eq displayed-month 1)
                               (1- displayed-year)
                             displayed-year)))))
            "Winter Solstice Festival"))))
```

This code is used to calculate the [winter solstice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongzhi_%28solar_term%29). I also knew that these 24 [solar terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term) are needed for calculating [Chinese calendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_calendar). So I wonder how to calculate all the 24 solar terms in Lisp.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in Chinese calendar, please refer to this repo for details.

https://github.com/xwl/cal-china-x

The solar terms can be calculated with the following code after you install `cal-china-x`

```lisp
;;;###autoload
(defun holiday-solar-term (solar-term str)
  "A holiday(STR) on SOLAR-TERM day.
See `cal-china-x-solar-term-name' for a list of solar term names ."
  (cal-china-x-sync-solar-term displayed-year)
  (let ((terms cal-china-x-solar-term-alist)
        i date)
    (while terms
      (setq i (car terms)
            terms (cdr terms))
      (when (string= (cdr i) solar-term)
        (let ((m (caar i))
              (y (cl-caddar i)))
          ;; displayed-year, displayed-month is accurate for the centered month
          ;; only. Cross year view: '(11 12 1), '(12 1 2)
          (when (or (and (cal-china-x-cross-year-view-p)
                         (or (and (= displayed-month 12)
                                  (= m 1)
                                  (= y (1+ displayed-year)))
                             (and (= displayed-month 1)
                                  (= m 12)
                                  (= y (1- displayed-year)))))
                    (= y displayed-year))
            (setq terms '()
                  date (car i))))))
    (holiday-fixed (car date) (cadr date) str)))
```